# retrieve data between two date (m-d format) in mysql

Tags: mysql, date, between

I have a `my_table` that looks like this:

```
   -id-  -name-  -birth_date-
    01    AAA     1990-01-13
    02    BBB     1992-02-05
    03    CCC     2010-02-11
    04    DDD     1989-02-10
    05    FFF     2000-03-19
    06    GGG     1980-11-04
    07    EEE     2003-10-11

    ...  ...      .........
```

I want to retrieve all rows where `birth_date` is between two days of the year (as in, `mm-dd`, not `yyyy-mm-dd`).

If I had a specific year, I could write something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table 
WHERE birth_date >= '2012-01-01'
AND birth_date <= '2012-03-11'
```

But I want to find rows regardless of the year — something like this (non-working example):

```
SELECT * FROM my_table 
WHERE birth_date >= '01-11'
AND birth_date <= '01-11'
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

To get records with birthdates between January 11th and March 11th, you can write:

```
SELECT *
  FROM my_table
 WHERE DATE_FORMAT(birth_date, '%m-%d') >= '01-11'
   AND DATE_FORMAT(birth_date, '%m-%d') <= '03-11'
;
```

Note that to get records with birthdates between (for example) December 11th and January 11th, you would need to use `OR` instead:

```
SELECT *
  FROM my_table
 WHERE DATE_FORMAT(birth_date, '%m-%d') >= '12-11'
    OR DATE_FORMAT(birth_date, '%m-%d') <= '01-11'
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `MONTH()` and  `DAYOFMONTH(date)` functions of MySQL Date and Time.

```
SELECT * FROM my_table
WHERE (MONTH(date_column)>2 AND (DAYOFMONTH(date)>11)
  AND (MONTH(date_column)<4 AND (DAYOFMONTH(date)<15)
```